# AutoMapper TypeConverter custom constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper

Hi I am using AutoMapper to move from a Model to a Dto and it's working great.
In one `TypeConverter` I need to inject an Interface (a service) that has to be used by the type converter in order to do the conversion.

How can I accomplish this in AutoMapper?

Comment: Which Dependancy injection package are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you not just create a constructor on your `TypeConverter` class, accepting the service? Rather than using the generic `ConvertUsing`, pass in a new instance of your `TypeConverter` constructed with the service...

```
    public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter<String, String>
    {
        public MyTypeConverter(IMyService service)
        {
            MyService = service;
        }

        public IMyService MyService { get; set; }

        protected override string  ConvertCore(string source)
        {
            //use service
        }
     }
```

Usage:

```
     Mapper.CreateMap<string, string>()
                     .ConvertUsing(new MyTypeConverter(_myService));
```

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know I can do that. I was using the other method ConvertUsing<T>()

Comment: If the service that you require is `IMapper` then the readily available `ResolutionContext context` in the `ITypeConverter<>.Convert()` method provides the current mapper.

Comment: great comment Chris Walsh homie